# Correct setting for Win2008R2 home folder auto creation?

Tags: ntfs, windows-server-2008-r2

I have some problems creating a home redirection in a WinXP / Server2008 environment.

GPO states to redirect home folder to server share, but the folder for the user is not created. After refreshing my knowledge about some NTFS-Settings i still wonder:

a) What is the minimum security requirement for the NTFS-directory, where the user home folder should be created. The user should neither be able to delete the folder nor to write something into the parent folder.

b) What is the minimum requirement for the Network share.

c) What USER (System? User? OWNER-CREATOR? ..?) does create the directory and therefore needs write-right to the dir containing homefolders?

So if you have..

server "server" ntfs:

drive:\home\user1
drive:\home\user2

and drive:\home is shared as \\server\home

what should be the minimum settings on drive:\home and on \\server\home to allow the server to automatical create a user dir drive:\home\%username% if a user logs on the first time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the worst ideas Microsoft ever had was to translate administrative SYSTEM-NAMES into local languages. After figuring out, how it might be called in English, if found the following article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/274443/en-us

So it is for **NTFS** to the folder hosting the home direcories:

```
CREATOR OWNER - Full Control (Apply onto: Subfolders and Files Only)
System - Full Control (Apply onto: This Folder, Subfolders and Files)
Domain Admins - Full Control (Apply onto: This Folder, Subfolders and Files)
Everyone - Create Folder/Append Data (Apply onto: This Folder Only)
Everyone - List Folder/Read Data (Apply onto: This Folder Only)
Everyone - Read Attributes (Apply onto: This Folder Only)
Everyone - Traverse Folder/Execute File (Apply onto: This Folder Only)
```

and for **Share permissions** *everyone full control*, so no further restriction on network level.